# Node.js Api, can't delete from database

Tags: node.js, api

I'm working on an `Angular` project so I wanted to make a simple `Rest API` to handle a `MySql database`, that's why I made one in Node.js but when I tried to delete an item with `id = 3`, I'm only getting an error that looks like this:

```
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'DELETE FROM recipies WHERE id = ?'
```

So I wanted to ask for help. I was thinking that I'm getting this error because these few lines had some logic problems:

```
Recipe.remove = (id, result) => {
    sql.query("DELETE FROM recipies WHERE id = ?", id, (err,res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
            result(null, err);
            return;
        }
        if (res.affectedRows == 0) {
            // not found recipe with the id
            result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
            return;
        }
        console.log("deleted customer with id: ", id);
        result(null, res);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typo appeared:
**recipeID**, should be **recipeId**

But mods edited my post so you will probably never know where...

**Remember, always see if you have typos**

Answer (score 2):

The error message was telling you all along!

In NodeJS, to replace query arguments you list
them in an array as the second argument of the
query.

```
sql.query("DELETE FROM recipies WHERE id = ?", [ id ], (err,res) => {...
```

Comment: 1. Thanks for comment
2. Not working ;/ (
{
    "message": "Not found with id undefined"
})